# Need to display loading gif in a popover and then replace it with ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover that I want to populate with content via ajax.

So I have this:

```
$('.openMessagePopover').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
    $threadId = $(this).data('id');
    return getContent($threadId);
    }
});
```

and the function:

```
function getContent($id)
{
    $thisData = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: $threadURL +$id,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data); 
            $thisData = data;
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("error");
            $thisData = "No message found"; 
        },
        complete:function()
        {
            alert($thisData); 
            return $thisData;
        }
    }); 
}
```

The alert(data);  displays the correct data from the URL so that is  successful.

But it doesn't display it in the popover. Any ideas as to what I am missing would be great.

And what I really want is to have a loading gif to display in the popover content while the ajax content is loading.

This is where it gets massively confusing for me. Because if I change the getContent function to:

```
function getContent($id)
{
    return "<img src='/img/ajax-loader3.gif' />";
});
```

that works and the loading gif appears in the popover content....but I can't see why the previous ajax call doesn't?

I have looked at the similar questions that are available on SO but haven't found a solution that works for me. Also a lot of similar questions seem to have been asked some time ago which makes me wonder if I am not missing some really obvious new function currently available!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesomeness! Problem solved!

HTML:

```
<div class="popover-medium">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
    class="icon-entypo icon-chat btn-chat multi trigger openMessagePopover"
    title="Messages"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-placement="left" 
    data-html='true'
    data-id="2" 
    ></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.openMessagePopover').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
    $threadURL= "/api/getMessagesByThreadId/";
    $threadId = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: $threadURL +$threadId,
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $thisData = data;
        },
        error: function () {
            $thisData = "No message found"; 
        },
        complete:function()
        {
            return $(".popover-content").html($thisData);
        }
        }); 
    }
    })
    .on('shown.bs.popover', function() { 
    $(".popover-content").html("<img src='/img/ajax-loader3.gif' />");                
});
```

The 'shown.bs.popover' was the missing link! (And it helped to populate the popover-content correctly)

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I got a good solution for this problem, although a bit late but if someone need can follow this solution.

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    html : true,
    trigger: focus,
    content: function() {
       AsyncFunctionLikeAjaxCall(some_param)
       .then(function(result){
           $(this)[0].dataset['content'] = result;
           $(this).popover('show')
       }.bind(this))
       return 'Loading..'; // or <img src='/path/to/loading.gif'>
    }
})
```